# linear/nonlinear system definition

Tags: trigonometry, nonlinear-system

genmerally we know that linear system is defined by following two rule

$1.T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y);$

$2.T(c*x)=c*T(x) $

or  operation  on sum of  two income is equal  to sum of operation on each input and also  operation on input multiplied some constant is equation constant multiplied by operation on given input,now let us consider following model

$$
x(n) =  \sum_{p=1}^{P} a_p \cos(2\pi f_pn + \phi_p) + \epsilon(n)
$$

clearly $cos(a+b) \neq cos(a)+cos(b)$ and also $cos(c*a) \neq c*cos(a)$,so that means that system driven by sinusoidal/cosine model is not  linear right?thanks in advance

Comment: $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are not linear therefore $x(n)$ wouldn't be linear either.

Comment: What is your input/output relation? What do you mean by a "system driven by sinusoidal/cosine model"?

Comment: why i am asking in general AR/ARMA model it is suppose to fit for linear systems,but there it is not good choice to fit this model for this signal right?

Comment: i mean i have some frequencies,phases ,amplitudes and  time,relationship is  represented by this model,where epsilon is white nosie

Comment: @MattL..L  by this form,is that form linear?that was my basic question

Comment: An AR model can indeed be used to model a sum of sinusoids. An AR model models a signal as filtered white noise. We're not talking about linear systems here but about signal models.

Comment: but  for AR model,signal must be stationary right?

Comment: and  this signal  should not be stationary as i know,so how we can apply this model to this  model?

Comment: i am confused already,if i can  model sinusoidal model by AR,then clearly this model must be stationary right?if all components (frequency,amplitude,phase) are constants,they are not function of time,then this process must be non stationary right?